# Microsoft Lightswitch 2013 HTML Client Server Error - Configuration Error

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I published a LS 2013 HTML client to an IIS 7.5 server running on Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise Edition. I am getting the following error:

Server Error in '/HTMLClient' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

```
Line 151:        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 152:        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
Line 153:        <add assembly="Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
Line 154:      </assemblies>
Line 155:    </compilation>
```

The file that is referenced in the project, Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server.dll version 12.0.21005.1, is in the bin folder for the website. I used regedit to verify the .NET 4.5.1 is installed on the server.

It is assigned to .NET framework version v4.0.30319 in IIS. I think that should mean it is using 4.5.1, but I'm not sure because the version has been 4.0.30319 since .NET 4.0.

Please help me troubleshoot this error. I get the same error on a project upgraded from VS2012 to VS2013 and a brand new project created in VS2013

**Update: I am having the same problem with a VS2012 LS app. I think I have permissions set up wrong or something on the server. I am looking into it. Any thoughts would be appreciated. I have succesfully installed a LS 2012 Silverlight app and a ASP.NET Web Forms app to this server. I don't work with IIS that often...**

**Update 2: I am able to publish and run a Lightswitch 2013 Desktop Client on the server, but not a HTML Client. So it appears this server doesn't want to run HTML Clients. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was no bin directory in my HTMLClient folder. I looked in the root app folder and saw a bin folder and thought everything was okay.

I finally enabled assembly bind failure logging and saw that the bin path the app was looking for didn't exist.

Here is where I learned to enable the logging: [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)